# Android Studio push tags to remote

Tags: java, android, git, android-studio, bitbucket

I've recently started working with Android Studio and am using git (bitbucket).
Whenever I create a stable/releasable version of an application I create a tag so that it becomes easier to spot all the versions among all the commits.

My trouble is that I have not found a way to push my tags to the remote from within Android Studio (either manually or automatically). Until now I have been using `git push --tags` through the command line to do the trick.

Is there any way to make it from inside the IDE or do I have to stick to this not so neat way?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't push tags from IntelliJ IDEA/Android Studio.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-77483

**EDIT:**

The latest Studio and IDEA have [a "push tags" feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/push-dialog.html#d457155e255).
[image]

Answer (score 24):

In AS, go to VCS>>Git>>Tag...
[image]

in Commit, you don't need to write anything if you want tag your project HEAD. Click on Create Tag.

Then, check the box to push tags to your remote server
[image]

and Push.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Terminal window in Android Studio with this commands:

```
//push every local tag to remote
git push origin --tags

//push a specific local tag to remote
git push origin : tagName
```

These commands are usefull if you already have commited your changes

Answer (score 1):

Tags is useful for release build commit.
Once you connected with git tags can be created from Android Studio **Menu>VCS>Git>Tag..** Then push to that tag.